# What is the difference between Android API and Google API?

Tags: android, google-api

I have gone through some of the links that difference between the Google API and android API.I have not got clear explanation.Anyone Can you help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer for your question is below

**The google API includes**

```
    ->Maps and other Google-specific libraries.
```

**The Android one only includes**

```
    ->core android libraries.
```

Answer (score 1):

- There is a huge set of google apis for using all **google web services** !

  - google maps
  - google search
  - google app engine
  - google signin
  - ... (see google products: https://developers.google.com/products/?csw=1)
- Android API is part of the Android SDK (software development kit) and is to develop **android applications**.

You can note that Android API may be considered as a part of google APIs because it authored by google.

Answer (score 1):

Google API is for developing Google-based services such as Google Maps.
Android API is for developing Android apps.

Answer (score 0):

**google API**:-
it uses all google specific libraries like google map,search engine,sign in.

**Android API**:-
it is also a part of google API.
it uses all core android libraries.
Android sdk holds Android API.
ref[enter link description here](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/?_ga=2.191402666.1013067134.1602357801-468895276.1598548016)

Comment: Please provide reference links for this information. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.